# How to update ConcurrentHashMap and return previous value

Tags: java, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I have some functions that increment or set a value in a `ConcurrentHashMap` which are working fine. I also have a function that sets a value to `0`. I would like that function to return the previous value. As an example, this function will return `0` but I would like to know the value before it was set to `0`

```java
public static long zeroValue(String mapKey) {
    return concurrentMap.compute(mapKey, (key, val) -> 0L);
}
```

If I do this I get an error that ret must be final. Making it final then doesn't allow me to put a value in it though,

```java
public static long zeroValue(String mapKey) {
    long ret;
    concurrentMap.compute(mapKey, (key, val) -> { ret = val; return 0L; });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map.put` returns the old value, so instead of `compute` you could use

```java
public static long zeroValue(String mapKey) {
    return concurrentMap.put(mapKey, 0L);
}
```

From `Map.put` documentation:

> Returns:
> the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key, if the implementation supports null values.)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had fallen into the trap of assuming the solution was going to difficult so was off searching for a complex solution :-)

Comment: @MikeKulls Also, it is better to use `put` in scenarios where the value is a constant. `compute` would require an unwanted lambda

Comment: Thanks, good tip. These are used in a high volume data streaming situation with 15 threads so every saving helps.